# How to copy font weight and size from a PDF to CSS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, css, google

I'm struggling with an issue where I'm given designs for websites in PSDs and they use Google Font fonts and trying to match them when building the site in HTML/CSS.

Is there something i'm missing in terms of being able to match the font sizes and weights with that in the design? The sizes in the photoshop file don't match reality at all, and the font weights look wrong on my Windows machine when trying to match.

Comment: Font sizesare only meaningful if your document is set to 72 DPI

Comment: This is a large reason the workflow of full building Photoshop mockups for web pages/site lost traction 10 years ago.

Comment: @joojaa thanks, i'll try getting the designer to work to that

Comment: @Scott thanks for your opinion but that doesn't contribute anything towards resolving the issue

Comment: Did the designers convert all text to bitmaps? If so, ask them ("please") to *not* do that and send you a new file.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, it's all as text layers. But matching the font weight to Google Fonts just looks really off, even though it's the same font?

Comment: Photoshop renders fonts in a different way than browsers. It has five different anti-aliasing methods (none, sharp, crisp, strong, smooth) which can make small texts look dramatically different. Font rendering isn't even consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The reality is, it's a guessing game and it's **never** going to match exactly.

I lost count of how many times I heard "that text doesn't match the image" and had to explain that live HTML text is a different animal than text in a raster image.

A great deal of this issue specifically is why building full page Photoshop mock-ups was a workflow I feel died in the early 2000s when CSS3 came along. Create sketches and wireframes, but actual buildouts in HTML/CSS often save **a lot** of time nowadays.

**The long and short of it is, you have to *eyeball it*.**

The only real solution is to utilize the settings from the image to get *close*, but then there's probably a need to tweak the CSS to get a little closer to the image. This is often quite easy for sizes. However, for weight it can be a nightmare. A great deal of type in a raster image may appear bolder or thinner than HTML type - much of this is related to any anti-aliasing method/setting in the image itself, not necessarily the typeface. For weights, which are impossible to match due to anti-aliasing, you can only *explain* things to the client.

This is akin to trying to match colors on every possible monitor... it's simply something that is not going to happen most of the time. The only real option is to *educate* the client as to what is and is not possible given the delivery medium.